# How can I use add_filter for a specific page template?

Tags: wordpress, filter

In Wordpress I have a page template called `designers.php`.

When loading, it reads the `slug` to get a uniqe ID, then calls the DB to retrieve designer information.
I want to use this information to alter the page title, using the designer name in the title tag.

I've tried using the `add_filter` in my `designers.php` file, but it's not working:

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'set_page_title');

function set_page_title($title) { 
  global $brand;
  return 'Designer '.$brand['name'].' - '.get_bloginfo('name');  
}
```

I'm, guessing the `add_filter` must either be located inside a plugin or in `functions.php` file.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

**UPDATE**
The function is never fired as long as I use `wp_title`. If I change it to `init` (for testing), the function is fired.

So why does the `add_filter`nor work for `wp_title`?

Comment: Which version of Wordpress are you using ?

Answer (score 4):

You are almost right. The filter must reside in function.php, and is called to modify the title. You can add the filter conditionally. Use this function [is_page_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) to determine if wordpress is rendering your template

Try to modify your function like this:

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'set_page_title');

function set_page_title($title) { 
  global $brand;
  if (is_page_template('designer.php')) 
     return 'Designer '.$brand['name'].' - '.get_bloginfo('name');   
  else
     return $title;
}
```

Comment: @keatch - That's not working. I've placed the function and the `add_filter` in `functions.php`, but the function is not called. Testing with `echo 'TEST';` before the IF.

Comment: In my installation, this piece of code is working fine! Did you have other plugins that could be modify your title, like SEO plugins, after that your function is called? To test if your function is called, try this gist: https://gist.github.com/717a938919cf16c5854d. Look at your source code in your page!

Comment: @keatch - I have no other plugins that modifies title as far as I know. No SEO plugin. Tested your code at gist, no output (in in source code either) :(

Comment: @keatch - If I change `wp_title` to `init`, it works . `$wp_query` is outputed.

Comment: @keatch - I'm using the latest version.

Comment: The reason that won't work is because is_page() and is_page_template() conditionals won't work inside the loop. You can use them after the loop if you do wp_reset_query(). It's a frustrating details that's under-documented.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `add_filter` must either be located inside a plugin or in `functions.php` file.

Then, maybe you have to set the priority for the filter :

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'set_page_title',1);

function set_page_title() { 
  global $brand;
  return 'Designer '.$brand['name'].' - '.get_bloginfo('name');  
}
```

And check the `<title>` meta in your `header.php` theme.

```
<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```